# Limiting Length of Input in JTextField is not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, document, jtextfield

I am trying to limit the max length of character a user can input in a textfield but It seems to be not working.

Here is the code:

```
text2 = new JTextField("Enter text here",8);
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? How can I make the limit to work properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constructor

```
new JTextField("Enter text here",8);
```

sets the number of visible columns to 8 but doesn't restrict you from entering more.

You could use a [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586395/jtextfield-how-to-limit-the-number-of-charaters) to restrict the input length.

Comment: You can find a good example on how to do this here (http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/LimitJTextFieldinputtoamaximumlength.htm).

Answer (score 19):

You current code is not setting the maximum length, rather it is defining the number of visible columns.

To restrict the maximum length of the data, you can set a custom [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) for the text field that does not permit additions that break the maximum length restriction:

```
public final class LengthRestrictedDocument extends PlainDocument {

  private final int limit;

  public LengthRestrictedDocument(int limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
  }

  @Override
  public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
      throws BadLocationException {
    if (str == null)
      return;

    if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
      super.insertString(offs, str, a);
    }
  }
}
```

Then set your text field to use this document:

```
text2.setDocument(new LengthRestrictedDocument(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply extend the JTextField Class and override the KeyReleased event in the constructor and point it on a new method that checks the length:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class RecordClassTextField extends JTextField {

    public RecordClassTextField() {
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                cleanText();
            }
        });
    }

    private void cleanText()
    {
        if(this.getText().length() > 17){
            System.out.println("Over 17");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this method will not work with Paste, use custom PlainDocument

Answer (score -1):

No need to use any `API`
Simply write this code on `TextFieldKeyTyped`  event

```
if (jTextField.getText().trim().length() == 8 || evt.getKeyChar() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        evt.consume();
    }
```

And before using this code set `JTextField` property `setTransferHandler(null);` that will prevent from pasting.

Comment: this method will not work with Paste, use custom PlainDocument