# Limit textfield input to number of columns / conflict with DocumentFilter

Tags: java, netbeans, maskedtextbox, jformattedtextfield, documentfilter

I have a WWFormattedTextField:

```
public class WWFormattedTextField extends JFormattedTextField implements FocusListener {

private DocumentFilter filter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();
private boolean limitToMaxInput = false;

public WWFormattedTextField() {
    super();
    init();
}

private void init() {
    addFocusListener(this);
//This line makes ALL text in ALL textfields uppercase as they type
    ((AbstractDocument) this.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
}

//This method uses value of colulmn property of textfield and creates a mask
//that limits the amount of characters
public void setLimitToMaxInput(boolean limitToMaxInput) {
    int columns = getColumns();
    String patternLimit = "";
    while (columns > 0) {
        patternLimit = patternLimit.concat("*");
        columns -= 1;
    }
    try {
        setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter(patternLimit)));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WWFormattedTextField.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    this.limitToMaxInput = limitToMaxInput;
}
```

My problem is that the setLimitToMaxInput overwrites the UppercaseDocumentFilter. The field is limited to number of columns, but because the mask is * - when user types - it doesn't uppercase it...

Need some helpful hints or suggestions towards the correct way to achieve my goal: an always upprercase textfield that limits(stops) user input when max size (columns) is reached.

Code for the UppercaseDocumentFilter:

```
public class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter{
    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586395/jtextfield-how-to-limit-the-number-of-charaters)

Apparently I didn't have to bother with that clunky mask and just use DocumentFilter for both: uppercase and limiting input.